# Java Swing vomits font information to std out

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have a Java program that I have written in Eclipse running in jdk1.8.0_73 on Ubuntu 14.04

```
public class Vomit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Font font = new Font("Helvetica", 72, Font.BOLD);
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setText("Vomit!!");
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Without any expiation, the frame is created at the minimum size and no text is displayed in the frame. Even stranger, my console output gets filled with a ton of font information.

Here is an example of a small segment of the output:

```
Font 244 Pattern has 17 elts (size 17)
    family: "URW Palladio L"(w)
    style: "Italic"(w)
    slant: 100(i)(w)
    weight: 80(i)(w)
    width: 100(i)(w)
    foundry: "urw"(w)
    file: "/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052023l.pfb"(w)
    index: 0(i)(w)
    outline: True(w)
    scalable: True(w)
    charset: 
    0000: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 7fffffff 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    0001: ffffffff ffffffff fffff3ff ffffffff 00040000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0002: 0f000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 3f0002c0 00000000
    0003: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00100000 10000000 00000000 00000000
    0004: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 00000000 cf0ff000 0c0dcc00 faff0007 033ffffc
    0020: 77180000 06010047 00000010 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000
    0021: 00400000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0022: 46260044 00000000 00000000 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    0025: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000400 00000000
    00f6: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 000001f8 00000000
    00fb: 00000006 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
(w)
    lang: aa|af|av|ay|be|bg|bi|br|bs|bua|ca|ce|ch|co|cs|cv|da|de|en|eo|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fo|fr|fur|fy|gd|gl|gv|ho|hr|hu|ia|id|ie|ik|io|is|it|ki|kl|kum|kv|la|lb|lez|lt|lv|mg|mh|mk|mo|mt|nb|nds|nl|nn|no|nr|nso|ny|oc|om|os|pl|pt|rm|ro|ru|sel|sk|sl|sma|smj|so|sq|sr|ss|st|sv|sw|tk|tl|tn|tr|ts|uk|uz|vo|vot|wa|wen|xh|yap|zu|an|crh|csb|fil|hsb|ht|jv|kj|ku-tr|kwm|li|mn-mn|ms|na|ng|pap-an|pap-aw|rn|rw|sc|sg|sn|su|za(w)
    fontversion: 0(i)(w)
    fontformat: "Type 1"(w)
    decorative: False(w)
    hash: "sha256:64e4ba5bda2703d21a716b730570c3f401e75dcde74b23957de27bcab3f81680"(w)
    postscriptname: "URWPalladioL-Ital"(w)
```

There are many more of these. When I pipe std out to a file there are almost 40,000 lines of this nonsense.

The exact same thing sometimes happens when I launch "xscreensaver-demo". Is this a problem with Java Swing (I don't even know that xscreensaver-demo uses Swing)? What is going on here?

Comment: BTW - `Font font = new Font("Helvetica", 72, Font.BOLD);` should best be `Font font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, 72, Font.BOLD);` (or rather the variant suggested below) for cross-platform compatibility. (This windows box does not have Helvetica installed, but it has other sans serif fonts that can be used.)

Answer (score 2):

For the JFrame showing it at minimum size, you have this line wrong:

```
Font font = new Font("Helvetica", 72, Font.BOLD);
```

Should be:

```
Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 72);
```

Comment: Right I did get the args backwards. Well the console output is the same but the text and frame are now visible.